# Mui different result when wrapping up component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to wrap up Material-UI Step component, but I end up getting different results visually

```js
export const MyStep: FC<TProps> = ({ label, error = false, Icon, key }) => (
  <StepMui key={key}>
    <StepLabelMui>{label}</StepLabelMui>
  </StepMui>
);
// To render
  return (
    <Stepper activeStep={0} orientation="horizontal">
      <ZaidStep key={0} error={false} label={"I'm first"} />
      <ZaidStep key={1} error={false} label={"Second"} />
    </Stepper>
  )
```

Result can be seen to be incorrect as there is not step icon as well as a connecting line that is not supposed to be there at the first element
[image]

While If I don't use the wrapped up component, but directly the Mui component, I get the right result

```js
    <Stepper activeStep={0} orientation="horizontal">
      <StepMui key={0}>
        <StepLabel>I'm first</StepLabel>
      </Step>
      <Step key={1}>
        <StepLabel>I'm Second</StepLabel>
      </Step>
    </Stepper>
```

Result can be seen to be correct as visually there exists Step Icon 1 and 2 next to the label
[image]

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

EDIT: solution was to spread the step props in the wrapper:

```js
export const MyStep: FC<TProps> = ({ label, error = false, Icon, key, other }) => (
  <StepMui key={key} {...other}>
    <StepLabelMui>{label}</StepLabelMui>
  </StepMui>
);
```

Comment: Yes, your edited solution is the correct one !!

Comment: Questions should be answered in the "Answers" part, not edited into the question.